# "Hardware-based" facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For my company I am developing an automated photo-booth. The goal is to capture a photo and after a quick review publish the photo to the company's Facebook page, all automated.
To this end I registered an app, and the application is conceptually done and works.
However only the developers of the app can see the photos, which seems to be because the app is not "reviewed by facebook" yet.
When I read what is required to get it reviewed, facebook needs to be able to test and verify the app. This is however impossible because the app only works in combination with the hardware on site, and it is not meant for anyone else to use it.

Am I solving this the right way? Can it be approved just for some users, like a "private" app? I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no user authorization is involved and you only use an Extended Page Token for that Page (that is valid forever), you don´t need to go through review. Just set the App to public in the "Status & Review" section of your App settings.

The App will work without review for everyone with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester).